# Calculating direction traveling around a circle? (knowing when to move CW vs CCW)

Tags: linear-algebra, circles, geometric-construction

I have a point I am animating that is traveling around a compass. The point should always move in the direction of what would be the shortest path. I have something like this at the moment:

```
step = 1
current = 30
end = 90

if abs(current - end) / 180 > 1
  step *= -1

while current != end
  current += step

  if current < 0
    current += 360

  if current >= 360
    current = mod(current, 360)

  do_animation(current)
```

This gets me what I want but I was wondering if there was a more efficient and formulaic solution out there?

Comment: I think this might be wrong if current = 30 and end = 270. Then you want to move clockwise.

Comment: @ethan yeah, copy/paste fail. I was summarizing the code from a more complex real-world implementation. I'll fix

Comment: The code is probably fast enough as is (unless it's deeply buried in some graphics routine called often) and easy to read. A formula would have to do the same work, with max and absolute value to implement the logic. Stick with human readable.

Comment: You could indeed combine the update of current into one line like `current=mod(current+step+360,360)`, but I would think that may be slower. It's hard to tell these days without benchmarking it. By the way, your set up of the step value is still wrong as written here. You're probably missing the initial setting of step to +-1 according to whether end or current is bigger.